# Viewing the source code of a specific URI

Tags: php, html, view-source

I m trying to view the source code of this particular page in naaptol. but unfortunately its been redirected to failure or some other page.

How can i stop this redirection and view the source code.

Link :

https://www.naaptol.com/checkout/ordernowsubmit.html

Comment: Show us some code please...

Comment: sir, I don't have any code, i m just trying view the code of given link.

Answer (score 1):

You can not view the source code for this URI because the source no longer exists. If the page is open in your browser it will be the *locally cached copy*.

The reason for this is, that judging from your question, you are trying to view a shopping process page that has expired or needs additional authentication to view correctly; so the Server is instead giving you a replacement "failure" page.

This is standard practise in online shopping systems.

When browsers request pages to view the source *some* browsers will try and reconnect to the same remote page to "get" the original source code. If the page does not exist, as in this case, then that obviously can not happen.

Comment: That should be the comment

Comment: @Shubh yes, but it is the answer, too.

Comment: In my experience, Firefox generally *doesn't* re-request the page, but Chrome does.

Comment: @IMSoP I'm not sure I think it may actually depend on the HTTP Headers received by the browser.

Comment: @Martin Ah, could be. HTTP caching is fiendishly complicated (or I'm just very bad at grokking it).

Comment: @IMSoP I have edited my answer to be a bit more general. Every time a Browser updates there's always new tweaks so these things are rarely canon.